# What type is "new { id = 0 }" in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm using `var abc = new { id = 0 };` in my C# code without knowing what type it exactly is!

Is is simply called an object? Is it a particular type of object?

I want to know coz I don't know how to add fields to this kind of object

Quick example:
I have `var abc = new { id = 0 };` and I want to add to `abc` the field `name = "david"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), that is, it does not have a type that you can use in code (though the compiler generates one).

MSDN says:

> The type name is generated by the compiler and is not available at the source code level.

If you want to add a property, you can simply do so:

```
var abc = new { id = 0, name = "david" };
```

Comment: I can only guess, but perhaps because it's not really correct. It *does* have an explicit type, it's just that the type is created by the compiler and doesn't have a name (other than internally for the compiler).

Answer (score 1):

It creates anonymous class object with one field called `id`. Look on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for details. Once you create object **it cannot be extended**.

This what this class looks like when open with .net Reflector

```
[CompilerGenerated, DebuggerDisplay(@"\{ id = {id} }", Type="<Anonymous Type>")]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<<id>j__TPar>
{
    // Fields
   [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
   private readonly <id>j__TPar <id>i__Field;

   // Methods
   [DebuggerHidden]
   public <>f__AnonymousType0(<id>j__TPar id);

   [DebuggerHidden]
   public override bool Equals(object value);

   [DebuggerHidden]
   public override int GetHashCode();

   [DebuggerHidden]
   public override string ToString();

   // Properties
  public <id>j__TPar id { get; }
}
```

So its compiled to regular class the basic difference is that it cannot be used outside of method scope.